# How do you attach this fence panel to a 4x4 post?

Tags: fence, post

For less elaborated fence panels you use hangers to support the horizontal 2x4 boards but with this desing that is not possible. These are pre made panels

[image]

Should I use this type of hangers at the bottom and screws at the top? Screws seems a little bit like patch work
[image]

Comment: Can't just screw through the outer frame?

Comment: I could but I am afraid it might crack

Comment: Then you need to do a little reading on carpentry. Pilot holes and countersinking will resolve that issue.

Comment: Your picture(s) need(s) to show well focused closeup detail at the end of the fence panel members before you can get any meaningful answer here. After all there are various styles of fence panels and each of them may be constructed differently.

Comment: If it is a pre-manufactured panel they should have a prescribed method, please consult the manufacturer or installation instructions.  These days they have to engineer for secure mounting, if they don’t a panel will fall on a small child and the lawyers will get rich....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hanger you have pictured is not correct for the panel you have pictured as the 2x4 is not oriented correctly for them.
 If you are not comfortable using just deck screws you could put an L bracket on the bottom of the panel to carry the weight of it and use a 1/4" lag bolt or carriage bolt at the top for lateral or shear strength

Comment: I don't think this was design to work with hangers

Comment: @MiniMe  Correct. You posted a question about using a specific hanger so i answered your question. It seamed like you did not think screws were sufficient so i gave you an alternative. You chose your own answer as the correct one yet you say it makes no sense to you to use screws. Your answer needs a more detailed explanation as to why it is the correct one as well as some punctuation and spelling corrections so it is makes sense to those who read it.

Answer (score 0):

The frame is made of 2x4s so yes you use scres to attach it straight to the post
Makes no sense to me to have that frame (at least the side edges) when you can use two hangers at the end of each traversal 2x4